# why python tesseract gives wrong bonuding boxes for letters?

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using python tesseract wrapper (tesserocr) over tesseract v4. I'm running some sample code over a simple "HELLO WORLD" white-on-black image, but although the letters are correctly recognised, I'm getting wrong bounding boxes, see the original image overlayed with results

[image]

Here is the code based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384732/how-do-i-use-the-tesseract-api-to-iterate-over-words). Any idea how to get correct bboxes? Thank you!

```
import cv2
import json
from PIL import Image
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI, RIL

img = cv2.imread('helloworld.jpg')
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
pillowImg = Image.fromarray(gray_img)
with PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
    api.SetImage(pillowImg)
    api.Recognize()
    ri = api.GetIterator()
    level = RIL.SYMBOL
    for r in tesserocr.iterate_level(ri, level):
        bbox = r.BoundingBoxInternal(level)
        symbol = r.GetUTF8Text(level)
        conf = r.Confidence(level)
        print(json.dumps([symbol, conf, bbox]))
```

And here is the output:

```
["H", 99.57249450683594, [185, 361, 234, 427]]
["E", 99.54733276367188, [251, 361, 292, 427]]
["L", 99.50984954833984, [311, 361, 353, 427]]
["L", 99.4959716796875, [362, 361, 404, 427]]
["O", 99.55082702636719, [420, 359, 472, 428]]
["W", 99.52144622802734, [529, 361, 589, 427]]
["O", 99.55513763427734, [589, 361, 611, 427]]
["R", 99.56971740722656, [647, 359, 721, 428]]
["L", 99.55563354492188, [756, 361, 779, 427]]
["D", 99.56954956054688, [807, 361, 861, 427]]
```

Answer (score 0):

it turns out "brew install tesseract --HEAD" brought me corrupted train files!

```
wget -O "eng.traineddata" "https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/master/eng.traineddata"
```

I also need to switch to Tesseract-only engine mode:

```
with PyTessBaseAPI(oem=OEM.TESSERACT_ONLY) as api:
```

and that's it