# Can pytesseract use ChoiceIterator to search over multiple matches?

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

Can pytesseract use ChoiceIterator to search over multiple matches? It seems to me that pytesseract is only an interface to the binary. [tesserocr](https://pypi.org/project/tesserocr/) gives access to the Tesseract API which allows the use of ChoiceIterator. Example [How do I use the Tesseract API to iterate over words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384732/how-do-i-use-the-tesseract-api-to-iterate-over-words)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pytesseract` "wraps" tesseract executable, which does not provide this feature. So you need to use `tesserocr` or you can use [tesseract API via cffi](https://github.com/zdenop/SimpleTesseractPythonWrapper/blob/master/SimpleTesseractPythonWrapper.ipynb).

You did not specify why you need ChoiceIterator. Maybe have a look at hocr output (which is supported by [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/tesserocr/).

Comment: I need ChoiceIterator to search over multiple matches as in the example I linked.

Comment: so your options are tesserocr and cffi